# How to SELECT multiple COUNT(*) columns with each GROUP BY having a different WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, join, group-by

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
  PersonId int PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Action (
  ActionId int PRIMARY KEY,
  PersonId int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(PersonId),
  ActionTime datetime NOT NULL
)
```

and the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Person (PersonId) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4)

INSERT INTO Action (ActionId, PersonId, ActionTime) VALUES
(1, 1, '2014-02-01'),
(2, 1, '2014-02-02'),
(3, 2, '2014-02-02'),
(4, 3, '2014-03-05')
```

I would like to run a query which shows the number of actions each person performs between the 15th of each month. For example, I am trying the following:

```
SELECT
    Person.PersonId,
    COALESCE(GroupA_Actions_Made, 0) AS GroupA_Actions_Made,
    COALESCE(GroupB_Actions_Made, 0) AS GroupB_Actions_Made
FROM
    Person
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            PersonId,
            COUNT(*) AS GroupA_Actions_Made
        FROM
            Action
        WHERE
            ActionTime BETWEEN '2014-01-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-14 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY
            PersonId
    ) GroupA ON GroupA.PersonId = Person.PersonId
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            PersonId,
            COUNT(*) AS GroupB_Actions_Made
        FROM
            Action
        WHERE
            ActionTime BETWEEN '2014-02-15 00:00:00' AND '2014-03-14 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY
            PersonId
    ) GroupB ON GroupB.PersonId = Person.PersonId
```

However, the query I am trying is returning the following:

```
PersonId | GroupA_Actions_Made | GroupB_Actions_Made
(null)     0                     1
```

but I would like

```
PersonId | GroupA_Actions_Made | GroupB_Actions_Made
1          2                     0
2          1                     0
3          0                     1
```

(I do not want the results to return anything for people who have not made actions.)

How can I obtain the results in the desired format?

**UPDATE**

Each of the answers works except that I had to wrap them as follows:

```
SELECT
    PersonId,
    GroupA_Actions_Made,
    GroupB_Actions_Made
FROM (
    -- (answer)
) t
WHERE
    GroupA_Actions_Made > 0
    OR GroupB_Actions_Made > 0
```

Using SQL Server Profiler, the accepted answer seems to have the fastest query time on large data sets.

Comment: Are you sure RIGHT outer join is the correct thing to use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you the result you wanted but I'm not sure if it's the most flexible piece of code.

```
SELECT p.PersonId,
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN a.ActionTime >= '2014-01-15 00:00:00' 
            AND a.ActionTime < '2014-02-15 00:00:00'
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
        END) AS GroupA_Actions_Made,
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN a.ActionTime >= '2014-02-15 00:00:00' 
            AND a.ActionTime < '2014-03-15 00:00:00'
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
        END) AS GroupB_Actions_Made
FROM
    Person p
JOIN
    Action a on p.PersonId = a.PersonId
GROUP BY p.PersonId
```

Comment: If you want to spare a couple of bytes you can use: `COUNT(CASE ... THEN 1 END) AS ...`

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```
select
    PersonId
    ,GroupA_Actions_Made
    ,GroupB_Actions_Made
    from (
        select
            p.PersonId
            ,[groupName] = 'Group' + case
                when a.ActionTime >= '2014-01-15' and a.ActionTime < '2014-02-15'
                    then 'A'
                when a.ActionTime >= '2014-02-15' and a.ActionTime < '2014-03-15'
                    then 'B'
                end + '_Actions_Made'
            from dbo.Person p
            inner join dbo.Action a
                on p.PersonId = a.PersonId
        ) pdata
    pivot(count([groupName]) for [groupName] in ([GroupA_Actions_Made],[GroupB_Actions_Made]))pvt
```

Also, [beware of between](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Answer (score 1):

This should be somewhat more flexible.

```
SELECT PersonId, [2014.02] AS GroupA_Actions_Made, [2014.03] AS GroupB_Actions_Made
FROM (
    SELECT ActionId, PersonId, 
        CONVERT(char(7), DATEADD(month,1,DATEADD(dd,-14,ActionTime)), 102) Grouping
    FROM Action
    ) p
PIVOT (COUNT(ActionId) 
    FOR Grouping IN ([2014.02],[2014.03])
    ) AS pvt
```